# How to display an error if the content of a <textarea></textarea> is empty using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I know how to display an error message if the user leaves a required input field blank when filling in a form, but I am not able to do the same with the textarea.

Comment: Maybe you can post some code and tell what *exactly* is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think on change fires for text areas as well so assuming it does

```
theTextArea.onChange = function(){
  if(this.value == ''){
     alert('You must supply a value for this field');
  }
};
```

or with jquery

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){
    $('#mytextarea').change(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      if($this.val() == ''){
         alert('You must supply a value for this '+$("label[for='mytextarea']").text());
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I would change this.value == '' to /^\s*$/.test(this.value) so it matches whenever there's only whitespace.